# My WampServer doesnt have apache setting in tray icon

Tags: php, apache, localhost, wamp, wampserver

This is how my tray icon setting looks like:

[image]

And this is what other tutorials say it should look like:

[image]

I'm pretty sure I installed WAMPSERVER 3.0.6 64bit

I dont have access to apache setting and modules

Comment: There's two menus - left click one and a right click one. 
If you're left clicking, right click.
If you're right clicking, left click.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Left Click** for the menu you are looking for ... **Right Click** is what you did to get the Setting menu.

The latest version of WAMPServer is V3.1.4 and you are strongly advised to upgrade to that version.

You can get it from the [backup Repo](http://wampserver.aviatechno.net/) or SourceForge. You can upgrade your version (3.0.6) directly using [this link](http://wampserver.aviatechno.net/files/updates/wampserver3_x86_x64_update3.1.6.exe) it will only upgrade the wampserver code and not effect any of the versions of Apache/PHP/MYSQL/mariaDB etc that you currently run